Obscure error when parametrized gtest with std::pairs fails
When using a parametrized test in gtest where the parameters are std::pair, when the test fails, the output is like
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] MyTest/MyFixtureTest.MyTest/1, where GetParam() =  (4-byte object <00-00 00-00>, 4-byte object <01-00 00-00>) 

How to pretty print the error, for example in case of enums showing the int or the enum value?
The test is something like this
enum class A
{
  A=0,
  B,
  C
};

enum class B
{
  A=0,
  B,
  C
};

B convertAtoB(A a)
{
  if (a==A::A)
  {
    return B::A;
  }
  else if (a==A::B)
  {
    return B::B;
  }
  else
  {
    return B::C;
  }
}

class MyFixtureTest :
  public ::testing::TestWithParam<std::pair<A, B>>
{ 
};

TEST_P(MyFixtureTest, MyTest) {
  A a = GetParam().first;
  EXPECT_EQ(convertAtoB(a), GetParam().second);
  
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(
        MyTestP,
        MyFixtureTest,
        ::testing::Values(
                std::make_pair(A::A, B::B),
                std::make_pair(A::B, B::B),
                std::make_pair(A::C, B::C)
  )
);


You mean public ::testing::TestWithParam<std::pair<A, B>> ? Otherwise it doesn't compile, because testing::Test base is missing.

Yeah, sorry you are right, the one I've used is for double inheriting also from an already existing fixture

Use the same technique as in Teaching GoogleTest How to Print Your Values. E.g. define PrintTo:
void PrintTo(const std::pair<A, B>& p, std::ostream* os) {
    *os << "(" << (int)p.first << "," << (int)p.second << ")";
}

You can also define operator<< for your enums to avoid casting to int.
As a side note, googletest knows how to print std::pair, it just didn't know how to print your custom types.

Google test is printing this since he do not know how to print those enums.
Here is repro: https://godbolt.org/z/qdYG4T7zb
If you provide printing function for those enums it will work out of the box. There is cool library which can solve this just in two simple lines:
#include <magic_enum/magic_enum_all.hpp>
using magic_enum::iostream_operators::operator<<; 

After just that output will be:
[ RUN      ] MyTestP/MyFixtureTest.MyTest/3
/app/example.cpp:36: Failure
Expected equality of these values:
  convertAtoB(a)
    Which is: C
  GetParam().second
    Which is: A

[  FAILED  ] MyTestP/MyFixtureTest.MyTest/3, where GetParam() = (C, A) (0 ms)

Live demo
Here you can see version which prints more information and will be more useful in a tests.
void PrintTo(A a, std::ostream* os) {
    *os << "enum A::" << magic_enum::enum_name(a) << " value(" << static_cast<int>(a) << ')';
}

void PrintTo(B a, std::ostream* os) {
    *os << "enum B::" << magic_enum::enum_name(a) << " value(" << static_cast<int>(a) << ')';
}

